# Make image over div, like stamp

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have div and want to put image like stamp to right top corner over div

Here is code what I already done

```css
.package-item-header {
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:20px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}
.package_stamp{
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/bPR0GVD.png') 50px no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="package-item-header">
  <div class="package_stamp"></div>
  GOLD
</div>
```

But it's just put it to right bottom corner of div, not over div.

How I can make it like this, but with transparent background?

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6acA6.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move the image over its parent by using negative `top` and `right` values in combination with `position: absolute`. `overflow:visible` ensures the image to be visible beyond the parent's borders, but is not neccessary in this case.

I also added `background-size: cover` in order to make the background-image fill out the element.

```css
.package-item-header {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
  float: left;
}

.package_stamp {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/bPR0GVD.png') 50px no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="package-item-header"><img class="package_stamp" />GOLD</div>
<div class="package-item-header"><img class="package_stamp" />GOLD</div>
<div class="package-item-header"><img class="package_stamp" />GOLD</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.package-item-header {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.package-item-header:hover .package_stamp {
  opacity: .5;
}

.package_stamp{
      height: 80px;
      width: 80px;
      background: url('https://i.imgur.com/bPR0GVD.png') no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      position:absolute;
      top:-25px;
      right:-25px;
      background-size: contain;
      z-index: 1;
}

img.package_stamp {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="package-item-header"><div class="package_stamp"></div>GOLD</div>
<div class="package-item-header"><div class="package_stamp"></div>GOLD</div>
<div class="package-item-header"><div class="package_stamp"></div>GOLD</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out  http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/328587/

```
.package_stamp{
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/bPR0GVD.png') 10px no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  position:absolute;
  top:5;
  right:0;
}
```